# Apply a function on multiple columns of a dataframe pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe with 30 columns. However I want to apply a function on 3 columns specifically. I have done something like this:

```python
# these are the 3 columns of a dataframe df and they are of StringType
date_columns = ['date1', 'date2', 'date3']

# my function
def convert_date(x):
    if x is '':
        return ''
    else: 
        return f.expr("date_add(to_date('1899-12-30'), cast(x as int))").cast(StringType())

# Want to do something like this
for c in date_columns:
    df = df.withColumn(c, convert_date(df[c]))
```

Is this the right way to achieve this? Maybe I am missing something here.

Comment: Your approach is fine, but the `convert_date` function won't work as written. Try: `def convert_date(x): return x if x == '' else f.expr(...your expression here...)`. The main difference is that you shouldn't use `is` to compare a column with a string value.

Comment: When I changed that, I get this error "ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions"